# How to get origin data of renderer console in electron

Tags: javascript, console, electron, renderer

The first, Happy new year 2021.

I'm working with ElectronJS. I want to control the console of the renderer.

In the main process, I have been listen event `console-message`.

But when I use `console.log` to print the object, I have received `[object Object]` message.

Example: I print:

```js
var a = {
    b: 'c'
};
console.log(a);
```

I have received: `[object Object]`

How can I get the value is:

```
{ b: 'c' } // <-- Origin data
```

Origin data maybe any type: `object`, `array`, `function` and any more.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Convert your object to String so you can print or alert it.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(a,null,2))
```

```js
//to print with functions, undefined, NaN, etc.

function printAnything(o) {
  var out = '';
  for (var p in o) {
    out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
  }
  console.log(out);
}

printAnything(a);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not fully described, the original data I mentioned could be other things like a `function`, so converting it into JSON is impossible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm leaving this project, I'll feedback to you after I get back